# How do I apply alt text when working with Retina-size images?

Tags: css, seo, background-image, retina-display, alt

I'm adding double-sized images to my web site, and then squishing those images back down with the CSS background-size property, which appears to be a common way to deal with our new high-res retina reality.

Is there a proper way to add alt text to a background image, or, how do I provide alt text for the images I'm working with with this technique?

I've considered using retina.js which would solve this problem, but then I'm using up bandwith serving a regular-size image and a double-size image.

I know there are other posts on stackoverflow and elsewhere that discuss alt text and background images, but the posts I've found date back to before retina displays.

I've seen posts that state alt text shouldn't be applied to background images, so what do people suggest?

Comment: Read this - http://webaim.org/techniques/alttext/#background

Comment: That's a really great primer on using the alt attribute, and I enjoyed reviewing it. Unfortunately, it doesn't help me in this instance. Maybe I just have to give up on the background-image, background-size approach for retina optimizing if I want to use the alt attribute... That's too bad, because it's an elegant solution, and I can swap 2x res with normal res using CSS and media queries, no scripts to run. I hope there's another way?

Answer (score 0):

#### Alt="Is for Meaningful Images."

Alt text is a generally necessary **if the image has meaningful content**. For instance, this photo of my laptop has content.

[image: meaningful image]

Images like this should be placed in an `<img>` tag with the appropriate alt text to **convey the purpose of the image in text form.**

On the other hand, background images, icons, patters, etc. these are not meaningful, content driven images. Rather, they are purely aesthetics and not contributing to the an article's content. These icons that link to something, that's what the `<a title="">` attribute is for, so use it.

#### ALT = Content driven images.

And BTW, you cannot add and alt tag on a background image, unless you cheat and add a `title` value on the tag of interest.

Comment: Thank you! I know how and when to use the alt attribute. I'm looking for a way to serve my double-sized images when a retina display is detected, without also serving a normal size photo at the same time which slows the download. The background-size property lets me do this by using media queries, but background images don't support the alt attribute. I'm looking for the best way to swap out my images and still be able apply alt text when Retina is detected.